# Using pyModis with ModisSwathTool

Tags: modis-reprojection-tool, pymodis

I am quite new to Python and starting to learn and use pyModis.

We know that **Atmospheric data (HDF files)** from Modis, like "MOD05_L2", only can be opened and managed using **"ModisSwathTool".**

In other words, MRT (MODIS Reprojection Tool) can **NOT** open those kind of HDF files.

As far as I read in the [pyModis website](http://www.pymodis.org) , pyModis is using MRT (MODIS Reprojection Tool) to work with the data.

Does pyModis work with “ModisSwathTool”?

Can pyModis manage and work with Atmospheric data from Modis, too?

Answer (score 1):

pyModis, specifically the **modis_mosaic** and **modis_convert** scripts can use *either* MRT *or* GDAL to mosaic and/or reproject the data (see [modis_mosaic.py documentation](http://www.pymodis.org/scripts/modis_mosaic.html)).

If pyModis somehow fails for your specific use case you can still use it to download the data and then reproject it with the Modis Swath Tool.